# How to use a dictionary for the following string?

Tags: python, string, printing

I am developing a script which is used to count the elements from a sequence given. I already found a way to improve this task, but i was wondering if it is possible to use a dictionary when the letters included in the string are not the ones that actually count and how to print then anyway.

For instance:

```
sequence = str(input('Enter DNA sequence:'))
print ('Your sequence contain:',len(sequence), 'bases', 'with the following 
structure:')
adenine = sequence.count("A") + sequence.count("a")
thymine = sequence.count("T") + sequence.count("t")
cytosine = sequence.count("C") + sequence.count("c")   
guanine = sequence.count ("G") + sequence.count("g")



print("adenine =", adenine)
print("thymine=", thymine)
print("cytosine=", cytosine)
print("guanine=", guanine)
```

I was thinking in a dictionary like this:
    dicc = {adenine:["A","a"], thymine:["T" ,"t"],
       cytosine:["C","c"], guanine:["G","g"]

}

But I dont know how to print those letters which are not nucleotides if they are given in the sequence, for instance, in the following sequence the result should be something like this:

```
sequence = AacGTtxponwxs:
your sequence contain 13 bases with the following structure:
adenine = 2
thymine = 2
cytosine = 1
thymine = 2
p is not a DNA value
x is not a DNA value
o is not a DNA value
n is not a DNA value
w is not a DNA value
s is not a DNA value
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter) (which is a `dict`-like class), you can be more DRY:

```
from collections import Counter

sequence = 'AacGTtxponwxs'
s = sequence.lower()
bases = ['adenine', 'thymine', 'cytosine', 'guanine']
non_bases = [x for x in s if x not in (b[0] for b in bases)]
c = Counter(s)
for base in bases:
  print('{} = {}'.format(base, c[base[0]]))
# adenine = 2
# thymine = 2
# cytosine = 1
# guanine = 1

for n in non_bases:
  print('{} is not a DNA value'.format(n))
# o is not a DNA value
# n is not a DNA value
# p is not a DNA value
# s is not a DNA value
# w is not a DNA value
# x is not a DNA value
```

Answer (score 0):

try this out

```
sequence = 'AacGTtxponwxs'
adenine = 0
thymine = 0
cytosine = 0
guanine  = 0
outputstring = []
for elem in sequence:
  if elem in ('a','A'):
    adenine += 1
  elif elem in ('T','t'):
    thymine += 1
  elif elem in ('C','c'):
    cytosine += 1
  elif elem in ('G','g'):
    guanine  += 1
  else:
    outputstring.append('{} is not a DNA value'.format(elem))
print ('your sequence contain {} bases with the following structure:'.format(len(sequence)))
print ('adenine = ',adenine )
print ('thymine = ',thymine )
print ('cytosine = ',cytosine )
print ('thymine = ',guanine  )
print ("\n".join(outputstring))
```

output:

```
your sequence contain 13 bases with the following structure:
adenine =  2
thymine =  2
cytosine =  1
thymine =  1
x is not a DNA value
p is not a DNA value
o is not a DNA value
n is not a DNA value
w is not a DNA value
x is not a DNA value
s is not a DNA value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Are you studying bioinformatics at HAN? I remember this as my assignment lol
#3 years ago
sequence = str(input('Enter DNA sequence:'))
sequence.lower() 
count_sequence = 0
countA = 0
countT = 0
countG = 0
countC = 0
countNotDNA = 0
for char in sequence:
    if char in sequence:
        count_sequence+=1
        if char == 'a':
            countA +=1
        if char == 't':
            countT +=1
        if char == 'g':
            countG +=1
        if char == 'c':
            countC +=1

        else:
            countNotDNA+=1


print("sequence is", count_sequence, "characters long containing:","\n", countA, "Adenine","\n", countT, "Thymine","\n", countG, "Guanine","\n", countC, "Cytosine","\n", countNotDNA, "junk bases")
```

There you go :)